# Changing Button Attributes in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make buttons only visible when a password is entered correctly. 
This is a WindowsFormApplcation..

So the part I am working on is a submit button the user clicks after typing in the password

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ( textBox1.Text == "password")
        }
```

Now the buttons I want to show are already their just set to hidden, and their names are button1 and button 2. I am a c# begginer and working my way through the basics. Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By 'hidden' I assume you mean their Visible property is set to false.

To show them, set their Visible property to true, like so:

```
if ( textBox1.Text == "password") {
  button1.Visible = true;
  button2.Visible = true;
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Yes sir, sorry for my vagueness. Exactly what I meant :)

Comment: or if you would like a one liner ...

button1.Visible = !button2.Visible = textBox1.Text == "password";

Comment: This oneliner hurts my eyes ;) Definitely not suited for C# beginners, even with quite some C# experience, I would never use such a construct as it is much too complicated to see what this should do (readability).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to put both buttons as visible, and add them to a panel container control. Set the panel control to Visibility = false, and just change the panel container to Visibility = true;

tip: [ctrl]+[alt]+[x] is keyboard shortcut for showing/hiding the toolbox, container controls are all grouped together.

Use the same password check/visibility change as mentioned by Jay's comment.

Comment: Good tip.  This is certainly a great idea for groups of controls.  I like to do it to 'mass set' the Enabled property too.