# Can I create a Hidden folder for Universal Windows Phone App?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to create a Hidden folder in public user data area (e.g `C:\Data\Users\Public\Videos`), and I have tried to implement it in C#, but I can't find relevant API, is there have a way to implement it in C++\CLI ?

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985091/hiding-directories-programatically-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because a normal application can't use the CreateFile() Win32 API (you'll get an Access Denied error code). And, as you pointed out, the C# API doesn't have any option for hiding files.

Comment: A little more detail: Even if there is a hidden folder in the library, it would not be visible through the WinRT API. The APIs hide any folder that is marked hidden or system.